# Is ManualResetEventSlim with spinCount = 0 the same as ManualResetEvent?

Tags: c#, .net, synchronization, manualresetevent

As far as I know, slim versions of synchronization primitives use spin waits before using resources of the kernel.

Is it true that `ManualResetEventSlim` with `spinCount` = 0 is the same as the usual `ManualResetEvent`?

```
new ManualResetEventSlim(initialState: false, spinCount: 0);
```

If no, what is the essential difference between them? Do we have any benefits of using the slim-version without spin waits?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source for [Wait](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/ManualResetEventSlim.cs,bf2a77e217d46448,references) if you set the spin count to 0 then it's basically a `ManualResetEvent` but instead of using a kernel wait event it actually uses a monitor.

The kernel wait event is only allocated if you explicitly ask for it, which save a transition into kernel mode to allocate it and set/reset it.

It's worth considering that although the `ManualResetEventSlim`  won't spin if you set the spin count to 0 it's highly likely that the call to `Monitor.Wait` will spin, so I suspect you're not actually avoiding a spin.